# Duplicating light along path in blender 2.8

Tags: light, path, instances

I've been following 'Create an Underground Subway Scene in Blender' from BlenderGuru in youtube.

When he started to duplicate the lights along the path using Duplicate menu in object tab he used an option called 'Frames' which, as I understand, duplicates based on frames generated by Follow Path option.

I was following the video using blender 2.80 beta and there is no 'Frames' option, nor 'Duplication' tab. I guess they changed Duplication to Instancing but Frames option is still missing. I tried to look for a solution to instance lights using 2.8 but most answers are made for older versions of blender thus I wasn't able to get past this problem.

What I tried so far:

1. Instancing with 'Verts' option. This did not work (I am guessing it is because light has no vertices)
2. Instancing with 'Faces' options. Failed, probably same issue as above.
3. Using 'Follow Path' constraint instead of Ctrl + P > Follow Path. Did not work either.
4. Using 'Motion Paths', even though i have no clue what it actually does, failed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: the use of a path for frame duplication is only optional, it will work without it in 2.7. The 'instancing equivalent' isn't available for 2.8.

Comment: I watched the video, he never used object tab for duplicating, I think he just Shift + D and moved it on a particular axis!

Comment: @Yash you probably didn't understand the question. I was trying to MASS duplicate along a path. I mean MASS, like 200 of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is going to help you but:

1 Create a light and a curve.

2 Convert the curve to Mesh.

3 Select the Light go to >> object >> Relations >> Parent (here, put the curve).

4 GO to the Curve >>Object >> Instancing >>Verts.

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: I was searching for a similar answer, worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you specify the amount of objects you'd like to duplicate?

Comment: It depends on the amount of vertices that you have, if you have 10 vertices, you will have 10 objects, if you have 5 vertices, you will have 5, and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can export the objects in .obj format to version 2.79 where you have the option to duplicate them, do the duplication and export it again at 2.80.
If you press Ctrl + Shift + A the duplicates will be real objects (instances) in case exporting as dupliframes did not work in 2.80.