# Converting Nurbspath into Mesh breaks is breaking my Curve Modifier?

Tags: mesh, light

I have been watching a tutorial from BlenderGuru in 2012 on how to make an subway tunnel in blender. I need to duplicate my light source along a path.

I figured out how to duplicate and make the lights sources follow along the path -- I figured this out from another question ([Duplicating light along path in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133333/duplicating-light-along-path-in-blender-2-8/133349#133349?newreg=4581137cbaf54ebfa66bcb9ae4d076ab)).

I followed the answers and it says I need to convert my path into a mesh, but when I do this, it breaks the path and none of my other objects will follow it anymore.

I new to blender. Not sure if this is just a thing? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Add a blend file.

Comment: Nevermind. I've found a makeshift way to work around it. Thanks anyway.