# Array of structures on a curve with increasing size, no deformation and equal distance

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create simple objects (e.g. cylinders) on a curve like a circle. The objects should increase in size but the distance between the objects should remain constant. Furthermore, I don't want the objects to be deformed while mapping them on the curve. I found several related questions, but they were outdated or missing one of the requirements I have.

For me it feels like something that should be rather simple, but I was not able to find a proper solution yet. What I found/tried so far:

- The "hack" with duplifaces which apparently made this work in the past was removed from blender.
- I tried to make an array of structures and map them with a curve modifiere on the circle. However, if I add an empty as the "object offset" (which seems like the way to go if I want to change the size), I get large deformations of my objects.

[image: Without scaling of the empty]
[image: With scaling of the empty]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicating light along path in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133333/duplicating-light-along-path-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question. With the provided answer I can multiply the object along the path. But it's not possible to set the distance since it is based on the number of vertices and I would like to have a rather smooth cycle. Furthermore, I see no option of changing the size of the object with this suggestion.

Comment: @Emir .. almost, but no scaling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be the right plumbing for your case:

- Create the curve to be followed
- Create a plane, an array of which will act as a mount for your objects
- Assign the plane an *Array* modifier, (Possibly set to fit your curve)
- Assign the array of planes a *Simple Deform > Taper*, along the array axis
- Assign the tapered array a Curve modifier, deforming it along your curve.

Now, in the plane's 'Object' tab > 'Instancing' panel, set it to instance from faces, with 'Scale by Face Size' checked. The 'Factor' can be adjusted:

[image]

- Parent your object to the array of planes:

[image]

You can adjust the interval, taper, scale factor, etc, and hide the instance original and the instancer from the viewport and/or renders.

Comment: Thanks alot! This seems to work very nice for my usecase. Just before reading your answer, I managed to find a somewhat similar approach. But instead of the Simple Deform -> Taper, I used an Array Object-Offset of the planes with an empty and scaled it in the process. Your method, however, is superior since it allows a constant distance between the cylinders and the height is not affected as much. Ideally, I would like to limit the scaling to the x/y dimensions but this is a optional. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @twife ! Thanks. You _did_ specify equal intervals.. :)   There's also a way with Geometry Nodes, if you want to have more control over the scaling on the way along your curve, but it's a bit more complicated.